# How to fix: JsBarcode "No element to render on." Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, barcode

I'm pretty new to JS and jQuery so please pardon me if I say/do something dumb. I'm attempting create a tool that will translate table data into a Barcode dynamically within an HTML Table using jQuery, and jsBarcode. I've got a working table but I get an error when I attempt to make the td translation to barcodes. I have a feeling is has something to do with the order of operations but I can't figure it out. Here's what I see in console and my table does not render when the button is clicked.

```
Console:JsBarcode.all.min.js:2 Uncaught NoElementException: No element to render on.
    at new e (http://127.0.0.1:61214/JsBarcode.all.min.js:2:9642)
    at j.render (http://127.0.0.1:61214/JsBarcode.all.min.js:2:23674)
    at x (http://127.0.0.1:61214/JsBarcode.all.min.js:2:22568)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:61214/index4.html:62:19)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:3:10316)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:3:8343)
```

JSBarcode requires an SVG tag with an ID to translate text into barcodes. Like this:

```
    <svg id="barcode"></svg>
```

Then some js or jQuery like this:

```
    JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi!");
    // or with jQuery
    $("#barcode").JsBarcode("Hi!");
```

I made sure to check that the jsBarcode Library doesn't break when used within tables. I've moved my script the bottom of my HTML in case is was an order of operations issue, but I'm still not convinced. Hence why I'm here!

The code runs fine and inserts the svg tags successfully with the correct id's according to the table data. but once I insert my javascript from jSBarcode with proper variables like this, it breaks

```
JsBarcode(canvas, currValue);
```

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Table</title>
    <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 250px; margin-right: 250px;">
    <button>Create Table</button>
    <div id="tableDiv" style="margin-top: 40px">
        Table will gentare here.
    </div>
</div>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Script:

```
<script>

      var json_obj  = {
          "name":"John",
          "age":30,
          "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda","550" ] }
    ]
 }

//Create table and fetch data from JSON Object.
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
              var number_of_rows = json_obj.cars.length;
              var k = 0;
              var table_body = '<table border="1" id="example"><thead><tr><th>Cars</th><th>Models</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
              for(j in json_obj.cars){
              for(i =0;i<json_obj.cars.length;i++){
                    table_body+='<tr>';
                    table_body +='<td>';
                    table_body +=json_obj.cars[k]["name"];
                    table_body +='</td>';


                    var currVal = json_obj.cars[k].models[i];//pulls data

                    var stringy = JSON.stringify(currVal);    //stringifies data| Needed?
                    var currValue = stringy.replace(/["']/g, "");//removes quotes and creates valid var
                    console.log(currValue);                     //logging
                    var canvas = "#"+currValue;                 //creates id string for svg tags
                    console.log(canvas);                        //logging

                    table_body +='<td><svg id="'+currValue+'"></svg>';//adds svg block to HTML with data specifc id

                    table_body +=json_obj.cars[k].models[i];     //adds data string

                  //JsBarcode(canvas, currValue);//jsBarcode Translation BREAKS CODE HERE!!


                    table_body +='</td>';

                    table_body+='</tr>';
              }
              k++;
            }
          table_body+='</tbody></table>';
          $('#tableDiv').html(table_body);
          //display data.......
    });

});
```

My goal is to make it add the barcodes within the TD tags according to the data within it.

Answer (score 0):

The variable canvas is a string in your example, but JsBarcode is expecting an Element or HTML DOM object. Like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(currValue);
```

or:

```
var canvas = $('#'+currValue)[0];
```

Not sure if this fixes your problem. I don't work with jQuery or JsBarcode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the script is running before the page has finished loading so it is not able to find the element with the ID you have specified to generate the barcode.

Place the script tags (JsBarcode, jQuery) at the bottom, that is before the closing body tag (`</body>`) or add a defer attribute to them at the top so it runs only when the page has finished loading and generate the barcode afterwards, like so:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" defer>
    </script>
<script src="JsBarcode.all.min.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem looks to be that the script is running before the page has finished loading, You should use this lifecycle method **updated**

```
updated(){
     JsBarcode("#barcode", "Hi!");
    }
```

Then it should work :)